# Change display format of date and time field in MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

My select statement in PHP is

```
  "select * from table";
```

I use the following PHP statement to display date & time of MySQL field.

```
  <?php
      echo $row['mdate'];
  ?>
```

The result come like this

```
  2010-03-09 16:59:18
```

I want to view the result in the following format

```
  09-03-2010 16:59:18
```

and I want to view the result in the following format

```
  09-03-2010 4:59:18 PM
```

without defining any extra function. I can only modify my echo statement.

```
  <?php echo $row['msgdate']; ?>

     or
```

I can also modify my select statement.

Comment: You should probably try to avoid using SELECT * in the future too, changes to your database implementation are more likely to have an effect on your code if you leave yourself to the mercy of selecting everything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the formatting directly in the database as Frank Heikens shows in his answer, or you can do it in PHP. Convert the mySQL date value to a UNIX timestamp using

```
$timestamp = strtotime($row["mdate"]);
```

then you can use all options of [**date()**](http://www.php.net/date) to format it, for example:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp); // returns 09-03-2010 16:59:18
```

both approaches are equally valid; I personally like to modify the value in PHP.

Answer (score 7):

See [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
select *, date_format(mdate, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s') AS formated_date from tabl;
```

And use formated_date in jouw php-code.

Comment: +1 My antwoord sou dieselfde wees, as ek vinniger kon getik. (Translation: My answer would have been the same, if I could have typed faster.)

Comment: ;) I do understand Afrikaans a little bit, sounds like dutch.