# PHP date time and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change date format (in DB or output) to dd/mm/yyyy - PHP MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480186/change-date-format-in-db-or-output-to-dd-mm-yyyy-php-mysql)
>   [PHP - Convert to date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671145/php-convert-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

mysql saves my date and times like this...

```
 2011-08-31 08:48:40
```

And when I echo them from the database this is how they appear, how can I get them to a universal format like m/d/y...

Or does it not matter if the mysql row is not a DATE_TIME and just VARCHAR and insert it into the database how I want it??

Thanks...

Comment: `date("m/d/y h:i:s", strtotime('2011-08-31 08:48:40'))`

Comment: erm... what you have there is an universal format. `m/d/y` is a locale format...

Comment: Thank you... put it as an answer and I will mark it as correct :)

Comment: Ye my locale format is universal enough for me

Comment: I gave you a hint and that's enough for me that you get it. You can pick any of the actual answer provided below.

Comment: @carlgcode *Can't tell if trolling or just ignorant.* :)

Comment: "Universal" as in "American"? Yeah...

Comment: @deceze not duplicate because of the mysql factor

Comment: @Alin Looks quite the same to me. Even if *that* question isn't a perfect duplicate, date format conversion is among the all-time most asked questions on SO with lots of precedent.

Comment: @deceze The question is trivial, and I'm sure that there are hundreds similar to it on SO, but it's not a duplicate of *that one*.

Comment: @Alin Okay, how 'bout this one then: [Change display format of date and time field in MySQL PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411970/change-display-format-of-date-and-time-field-in-mysql-php)

Comment: @Alin Pucaru No not trolling just that sarcasm doesn't come across a keyboard very well, thanks for your answer, has helped :)

Comment: Or this one: [Change date format (in DB or output) to dd/mm/yyyy - PHP MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480186/change-date-format-in-db-or-output-to-dd-mm-yyyy-php-mysql)

Comment: @deceze you must have alot of spare time to use on this site!

Comment: @carl I just know how to use the search function. :P

Comment: @deceze Voted as duplicate of the last link you posted. The other two are restricted to PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it [in PHP](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
date("m/d/Y", strtotime('2011-08-31 08:48:40'));
```

Or do it [in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2011-08-31 08:48:40','%m/%d/%Y')
```

*Of course you won't use hardcoded values in your code. You'll use the column name for MySQL or the retrieved column value, that's probably an element in an array, in PHP.*

Answer (score 0):

This post is previously answered:

[Convert to date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671145/php-convert-to-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Regards