# How can i show only hour and minutes?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working in php in which i am using mysql.

This is my function which is returning result in json format.

```
function getTiming($placeId) {

  $sql = "SELECT * from place_timing where placeId='$placeId'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

    $records = array();

    if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0)

     {

      echo '['.json_encode(array('placeId' => 0)).']';
      //this is for null result

     }

     else

     {

       while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 

       {

         $records[] = $row;

       }


       echo json_encode($records); //this concerts in json

     }

}
```

output of this function is like this:-

```
[{"placeId":"31","sun_open_time":"00:00:00","sun_close_time":"00:00:00","mon_open_time":"00:00:00","mon_close_time":"23:00:00","tue_open_time":"00:00:00","tue_close_time":"00:00:00"}]
```

But I want to show only hour:minutes.  means I don't want to show seconds.

please suggest me how can I change my above function so I can show only hour:minutes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This falls into the standard category of ["how do I format MySQL datetimes"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+%5Bphp%5D+change+time+format), for example [Change display format of date and time field in MySQL PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411970/change-display-format-of-date-and-time-field-in-mysql-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, the "cleanest" would be to specify the columns in the SELECT clause and pass the dates with [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) like this: `DATE_FORMAT(sun_open_time, '%H:%i')`.

Comment: this wont work if sun_open_time has data like only time format like hh:mm:ss.

Comment: It will work for both TIMESTAMP (which is the most commonly used type) and DATE_TIME; I'm not sure it will not work for TIME, but even then you can just switch to TIME_FORMAT().

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your query to select the actual fields, rather then * and then use [**TIME_FORMAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) on the time fields, like:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(`sun_open_time`, '%H %i') AS `opentime`;
```

That will return the desired values directly from the query without any PHP hacks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your fields of table place_timing (sun_open_time, sun_close_time and so on..) have only hh:mm:ss formated time. so you have to use SUBSTRING() function of MySql.

So you query could be as follows.

> $sql = "SELECT SUBSTRING(`sun_open_time`,1,5),
>   SUBSTRING(`sun_close_time`,1,5),  SUBSTRING(`mon_open_time`,1,5),
>   SUBSTRING(`mon_close_time`,1,5),
>   SUBSTRING(`tue_open_time`,1,5),SUBSTRING(`tue_close_time`,1,5)  from
>   `place_timing` where `placeId`='$placeId'";