# PHP MYSQL format Time to display in a table

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change display format of date and time field in MySQL PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411970/change-display-format-of-date-and-time-field-in-mysql-php)

I have a table with columns and information along with a date field which gets stored in a mysql database and displayed in a table in PHP which works fine in mysql but how can i output and format it correctly so it displays in a table row. I currently have this

```
    echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";
```

but it displays like this "2012-11-18 20:17:01". How can i format it correctly so it displays like 13 Dec 2012.

If it helps its for the creation of a user database. So it tells me when they first created their account.

Comment: Did you even try to google this? What did you try?

Comment: Yes i did and didn't find anything relevant to what i need.

Answer (score -1):

**(PHP 5 >= 5.4.0)**

```
echo "<td>" . (new DateTime($row['date']))->format('d M Y') . "</td>";
```

**(PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)**

```
$dt = new DateTime($row['date']);
echo "<td>" . $dt->format('d M Y') . "</td>";
```

**(PHP 4, PHP 5)**

```
echo "<td>" . date('d M Y', strtotime($row['date'])) . "</td>";
```